# how to convert an array to a graph or an array to an adjacency list

Tags: c++, graph, graph-theory

```
please i need help in converting an array to a graph or converting an array to an adjacency list. basically the problem is about reading a table in excel into c++
```

table.txt (an incidence matrix)

A B C D E
A 0 1 1 0 0
B 1 0 1 0 1
C 1 1 0 0 0
D 0 0 0 0 0
E 0 1 0 0 0
and representing the "matrix" as a graph and further finding subgraphs(clustering) in the graph. so the algorithm MCODE takes in a graph and find clusters. how do i convert an array that i have read my file into to a graph or an adjacency list

here is my code

```
#include <iostream>         
#include <fstream>            
using namespace std;    

int main()    
{    

 int array_size = 100048576;        
char * array = new char[array_size];    
int position = 0;    

ifstream fin("c:\\disc.txt");        
if(fin.is_open())    
{    
    cout << "File Opened successfully!!!" << endl;

    while(!fin.eof() && position < array_size)
    {
        fin.get(array[position]);     
        position++;
    }
    array[position-1] = '\0'; //placing character array terminating character

cout << "Displaying Array..." << endl << endl;    
  for(int i = 0; array[i] != '\0'; i++)
    {
        cout << array[i];
    }
}
else //file could not be opened
{
    cout << "File could not be opened." << endl;
}
return 0;
```

}

Comment: Instead of allocating an array of exactly 100048576 bytes: create a vector, query the size of the file, resize the vector to that amount, and then read the contents in one statement.

Comment: Can you clarify what you want help with? What format does your algorithm want the graph to be represented in?

Comment: the input data is a table( basically an incidence matrix). i want to read the table into a 2D array, but what my code is doing is a 1D array, which i cannot manipulate. i want how to read at 20X20 table into a 2D array.